# How to save a two dimensional array of custom object in a bundle?

Tags: android

I need to save a two dimensional array of custom object in a bundle to restore an activity after a screen rotation but I can't find an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Bundle.putSerializable()` as arrays are `Serializable`. You will need to make your custom class `Serializable` too. [Here's](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=45) a tutorial on implementing`Serializable`.

Comment: I think this is the best answer but the Aung Pyae's answer is very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

How about JSON?

Develop a method to convert your custom object into a JSON object, and add helper methods like "toJSON" & "fromJSON".

Then, you can create a JSONArray for an array of JSON Objects.
A 2D array of this object would simply be a JSONArray of JSONArrays.

Here's an example of what it would look like:

```
[
  [
   {"name":"john", "age":25}, 
   {"name":"david", "age": 40}
  ], 
  [
   {"name":"chris", "age":15},
   {"name":"howard", "age":55}
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Not a good idea, mate.** I would suggest to save it in somewhere else rather than Bundle. You could still use the same hooker methods onSaveInstanceState & onRestoreInstanceState for the purpose. But, Bundle objects are not designed to store complex data structure. The most it should be handling is a regular object. What you are having is not even an array. It is two dimensions array. You would require a lot of parsing states just to store / restore the data.

> How about you put that two dimensional arrays inside your own instance
>   of Application         object and access it from your Activity or
>   something ? If the device rotates, it will only restarts the Activity.
>   Not the Application. So, that is one possible solution.

Another one is blocking the Activity to restart when the device rotates. The entire purpose of restarting is to use the different resource for different layout form factor. If you are not using different layout file, you probably won't need the activity to restart.

Anyway, putting complex data outside the Activity scope always helps. There are a lot of state changes and restarting and lifecycle things in Activity. Usually, if you put complex data insides Activity, it is not stable and not reliable because it keeps on changing based on Activity states.

Hope that helps.